# Ionic2, how to get Google accessToken after Authorized using cordova-plugin-googleplus, Android situation

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, google-oauth, firebase-authentication

I need to sign the user in using Google OAuth and then get user YouTube channel info (readonly) inside an Ionic 2 application. Since Google stop inappbrowser auth flow in April 2017, my only option is to use cordova-plugin-googleplus to do that (http://blog.ionic.io/google-oauth-changes/).

However, after signed in with cordova-plugin-googleplus, in iOS I can get the accessToken in the response BUT not Android. So I need an extra step to get that accessToken so I can call Google YouTube API 3 to get user YouTube info WITHOUT a server. How to do that? Here is my code so far:

```
 googlePlusLogin()
      {
        if(this.platform.is('cordova')){
          //user is using it as an mobile app
          return this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            // In-App solution
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

              return GooglePlus.login({
                'scopes':'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
                'webClientId' : [web client id],
                'offline': true,
              })
                .then((userData) => {

                  console.log("userData " + JSON.stringify(userData));

                  var provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(userData.idToken);

                  let token: any;
                  let fullData:any;

                  token = userData.accessToken;

                  let headers = new Headers();
                  let googleAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings%2C+snippet%2C+id%2C+statistics&mine=true";
                  headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
                  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

                  return this.http.get(googleAPI, { headers }).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data =>{
                    console.log(data);

                    return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(provider).then((success) => {
                      console.log ("----Firebase success data------");
                      console.log (success);
                      fullData = {
                        uid: success.uid,
                        photoURL: success.photoURL,
                        name: success.displayName,
                        email: success.email,
                        youtube_channel : data
                      }
                      return this.userProfile.child(fullData.uid).update(fullData).then(_ => {
                        resolve(fullData);
                      });
                    }, (error) => {
                      console.log('error', JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
                      //resolve();
                    });

                  })

                })
                .catch((gplusErr) => {
                  console.log("GooglePlus failure: " + JSON.stringify(gplusErr));

                });
            });

          });
        } else {
          //In-browser solution
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
            let token: any;
            let fullData: any;
            provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly');
            firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(result => {
              token = result.credential.accessToken;

              fullData = {
                uid: (result.user.uid || ""),
                email: (result.user.email || ""),
                photoURL: (result.user.photoURL || ""),
                name: (result.user.displayName || ""),
                youtube_channel: {}
              }

              let headers = new Headers();
              let googleAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings%2C+snippet%2C+id%2C+statistics&mine=true";
              headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
              headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

              return this.http.get(googleAPI, { headers })
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(data => {
                  fullData.youtube_channel = data;

                  return this.userProfile.child(fullData.uid).update(fullData).then(_ => {
                    resolve(fullData);
                  });

                })
            }).catch(err => {
              console.error(err);
              resolve();
            })
          });
        }
      }
```

Please note in the code, I need to provide BOTH solutions with Firebase auth for mobile (iOS/Android) and web browser - as the app will be a progressive webapp, iOS and Android app. So I need all 3 solutions to be presented.

This code can successfully get user YouTube info and log user in my app with Google Oauth (via Firebase Auth) in iOS only, but not in Andorid. As Android will not return a `userData.accessToken`.

This is the step I don't know how to use Typescript, Ionic 2, Angular 2 to get the accessToken with the serverAuthCode. Since Firebase is my only backend, I do not want another node server to use the serverAuthCode to get the accessToken. Google recent change just make thing so complicated and frustrated.

Also, how to refactor my code to use the observable pattern so it is not filled with all the ugly return.

Appreciate all the help!

Comment: I am using similar code to the web section above, but am getting "401 Invalid Credentials" when I try to access `'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?key=' + this.apiKey + '&mine=true&part=snippet,id&maxResults=20'`. Any other pointers to get connected to youtube? After I get that working, I'll move on to IOS and Android.